# new Dart ByteBuffer from region of existing ByteBuffer?

Tags: dart

I'm loading binary files in a Dart web application that include compressed audio data as a portion of the binary data. When the data is loaded via http request, it comes in as a ByteBuffer, which I understand is Dart's substitute for a JS ArrayBuffer. The AudioContext.decodeAudioData() method requires a ByteBuffer, and I'm trying to figure out how to give it the relevant section of the loaded ByteBuffer. The loaded ByteBuffer contains additional data not related to audio. ArrayBuffers in JS support a slice() method, but I'm missing this in the ByteBuffer class, and I can't see any way to get back to a ByteBuffer after converting to any of the lists that would allow a range selection.

I imagine I could create a hybrid solution with raw JS, but if possible I'd like to keep this in Dart. Ideas appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I can't see any way to get back to a ByteBuffer after converting to
>   any of the lists that would allow a range selection

There are a few ways around that, but since you don't want to modify the original buffer (I guess), you will copy a few bytes around then:

```
// extract 2 ints (8 bytes) - no copying done yet
var rangeIterable = buffer.asInt32List().getRange(8, 10);

// create new typed list (copies the bytes from the iterable)
var newList = new Int32List.fromList(rangeIterable);
var newBuffer = newList.buffer;

print(buffer.lengthInBytes);
print(newBuffer.lengthInBytes);
```

Comment: Thanks very much! I think one tiny addition to this is that toList() should be called on the rangeIterable to work with Int32List.fromList(). It didn't even occur to me that the buffer property would be populated when creating a new Int32List. I had gotten used to that just being a reference to the original data, but of course it makes sense that it represents the copied data.

Comment: Did you really need to add the `.toList()`? Since it worked like that when I tried it out locally (without strong mode, that is).

Comment: I believe so. It was giving me a type conversion error when I tried it without it. "type 'SubListIterable<int>' is not a subtype of type 'List<int>' of 'elements'" Note that I'm testing in Dartium, launched from Intellij, and I think that might enable Checked Mode by default - would that do it?

Comment: Very well possible - I tried it in a console app :)

Answer (score 3):

The Dart `ByteBuffer` doesn't have a slice method. You can go thorough the `Uint8List`, so instead of `buffer.slice(a, b)` you do `buffer.asUint8List().sublist(a, b).buffer`. The `sublist` method on typed data lists returns a list of the same type backed by a new buffer, and the `buffer` getter returns the underlying buffer for any typed-data list.
It's not as pretty as the `slice` directly on the buffer, but it gets the job done without any alignment issues (the `Int32List` requires its start-offset to be 4-byte aligned, so for arbitrary cutting, always use an 8-bit list).

Comment: Thanks! That's a concise way to go and a good point on choosing a 1-byte list type.

Comment: Where does it say that `sublist` is backed by a _new_ buffer? All I can find in the [documentation](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.8.4/dart-typed_data/Uint8List/sublist.html) is that it returns "a new list". I tried it in DartPad and it seems to work, but I am concerned that it's an implementation detail.